# How to cut word which is having three digits in a file (100) - shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am having file, it has below data. I want to get queue names (FID.MAGNET.ERROR.*) which is having 100 + depth. please help me here.

file name MQData - [image]

Which command i should use to get queue names which is having 100+(three digits > + ) details?

Comment: An actual text instead of a screenshot would have been great, so people can play w/. your data w/o having to enter it.

Answer (score 1):

Three digits and >=100 have different meanings.

`0000` is more than 3 digits. well perhaps your data won't have those cases.

If the length is important, I will do `awk 'length($1)>2{print $2} file`
If the value is what you are looking at, I will do `awk '($1+0)>=100{print $2}' file`

The `$1+0` makes sure if your `$1` has leading zeros, the comparison will be done correctly too. Take a look this example:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{if("01001"+0>100)print "OK";else print "NOK"}'
OK

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{if("01001">100)print "OK";else print "NOK"}'   
NOK
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1 >= 100 {print $2}' MQData
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip lines with `grep -v`. I use `echo -e` to create a multi-line stream.

```
echo -e "1 xx\n22 yy\n333 zz\n100 To be deleted" | grep -Ev "^. |^.. |^100 "
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply